# Store Api response in model and share that response in multiple component

Tags: angular, typescript

## Details

I am calling an Api it gives me some response and I want to store it in to my mode I have created and the I want it to shared that model data into multiple component because I don't want to send request every time to get data because in responce there are two thing first is Product which contains many Apis and second apis. now when I want a specific api to that product I have to send another request which I don't want. because response gave me total data of product and apis is a single call. how can I achieve it.

## Response

```
[
  {
    "Id": 0,
    "ApimId": "5746ebcfcd7c3209247edc40",
    "Name": "Atea Service Desk",
    "Description": "Service Desk and Operations",
    "SubscriptionRequired": false,
    "ApprovalRequired": false,
    "State": "published",
    "Apis": [
      {
        "Id": 0,
        "ApimId": "5746ba28804136004d040001",
        "Name": "Echo API",
        "Description": null,
        "ServiceUrl": "http://echoapi.cloudapp.net/api",
        "ScopeId": 0,
        "WorkflowId": 0,
        "Workflow": null,
        "Scope": null,
        "CreatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:32.2553822+05:00",
        "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
        "UpdatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:32.2553822+05:00",
        "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
      },
      {
        "Id": 0,
        "ApimId": "574c167dcd7c3216c8c633b3",
        "Name": "Servicedesk and Operations",
        "Description": "Atea Servicedesk and Operations Internal API",
        "ServiceUrl": "http://dev-endpoint.atea.com/RFC",
        "ScopeId": 0,
        "WorkflowId": 0,
        "Workflow": null,
        "Scope": null,
        "CreatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:32.2564039+05:00",
        "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
        "UpdatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:32.2564039+05:00",
        "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
      },
      {
        "Id": 0,
        "ApimId": "574eb044cd7c320600975d85",
        "Name": "Swagger Petstore",
        "Description": "This is a sample server Petstore server.  You can find out more about Swagger at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).  For this sample, you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization filters.",
        "ServiceUrl": "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2",
        "ScopeId": 0,
        "WorkflowId": 0,
        "Workflow": null,
        "Scope": null,
        "CreatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:32.2574041+05:00",
        "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
        "UpdatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:32.2574041+05:00",
        "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
      },
      {
        "Id": 0,
        "ApimId": "574eb27fcd7c320600975d86",
        "Name": "Swagger Petstore API",
        "Description": "This API is design by Swagger.io",
        "ServiceUrl": "http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api",
        "ScopeId": 0,
        "WorkflowId": 0,
        "Workflow": null,
        "Scope": null,
        "CreatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:32.2584048+05:00",
        "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
        "UpdatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:32.2584048+05:00",
        "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
      }
    ],
    "CreatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:32.2594056+05:00",
    "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
    "UpdatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:32.2594056+05:00",
    "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
  },
  {
    "Id": 0,
    "ApimId": "57eb9930cd7c320760ee317e",
    "Name": "Non Workflow",
    "Description": "Workflow not applied to the contained APIs",
    "SubscriptionRequired": false,
    "ApprovalRequired": false,
    "State": "published",
    "Apis": [
      {
        "Id": 0,
        "ApimId": "574eb044cd7c320600975d85",
        "Name": "Swagger Petstore",
        "Description": "This is a sample server Petstore server.  You can find out more about Swagger at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).  For this sample, you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization filters.",
        "ServiceUrl": "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2",
        "ScopeId": 0,
        "WorkflowId": 0,
        "Workflow": null,
        "Scope": null,
        "CreatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:32.8218186+05:00",
        "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
        "UpdatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:32.8218186+05:00",
        "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
      },
      {
        "Id": 0,
        "ApimId": "574eb27fcd7c320600975d86",
        "Name": "Swagger Petstore API",
        "Description": "This API is design by Swagger.io",
        "ServiceUrl": "http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/api",
        "ScopeId": 0,
        "WorkflowId": 0,
        "Workflow": null,
        "Scope": null,
        "CreatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:32.8228184+05:00",
        "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
        "UpdatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:32.8228184+05:00",
        "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
      }
    ],
    "CreatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:32.8238186+05:00",
    "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
    "UpdatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:32.8238186+05:00",
    "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
  },
  {
    "Id": 0,
    "ApimId": "5746ba28804136004d060001",
    "Name": "Starter",
    "Description": "Subscribers will be able to run 5 calls/minute up to a maximum of 100 calls/week.",
    "SubscriptionRequired": false,
    "ApprovalRequired": false,
    "State": "notPublished",
    "Apis": [],
    "CreatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:33.4234324+05:00",
    "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
    "UpdatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:33.4234324+05:00",
    "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
  },
  {
    "Id": 0,
    "ApimId": "5746ba28804136004d060002",
    "Name": "Unlimited",
    "Description": "Subscribers have completely unlimited access to the API. Administrator approval is required.",
    "SubscriptionRequired": false,
    "ApprovalRequired": false,
    "State": "published",
    "Apis": [
      {
        "Id": 0,
        "ApimId": "5746ba28804136004d040001",
        "Name": "Echo API",
        "Description": null,
        "ServiceUrl": "http://echoapi.cloudapp.net/api",
        "ScopeId": 0,
        "WorkflowId": 0,
        "Workflow": null,
        "Scope": null,
        "CreatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:33.9833659+05:00",
        "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
        "UpdatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:33.9833659+05:00",
        "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
      }
    ],
    "CreatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:33.9843647+05:00",
    "CreatedBy": "LHR\\ahja",
    "UpdatedDate": "2016-10-04T18:49:33.9843647+05:00",
    "UpdatedBy": "LHR\\ahja"
  }
]
```

## Models

```
import {Api} from './api';
export class ProductModel {
    public Id: number;
    public Apim: string;
    public ApprovalRequired: boolean;
    public Name: string;
    public Description: string;
    public ServiceUrl: string;
    public State: string;
    public SubscriptionRequired: boolean;
    public Apis: Api[];
}

export class Api{
    Id: 0;
    ApimId: string;
    Name: string;
    Description: string;
    ServiceUrl: string;
    ScopeId: number;
    WorkflowId: number;
    Workflow: any;
    Scope: any;
    CreatedDate: string;
    CreatedBy: string;
    UpdatedDate: string;
    UpdatedBy: string;
}
```

## component

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {ProductService} from '../../services/product.service';
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {PaginatePipe, PaginationControlsCmp, PaginationService, IPaginationInstance} from 'ng2-pagination';
import { Router }  from '@angular/router';
import {NotificationsService, SimpleNotificationsComponent} from 'angular2-notifications';
import {LoadingComponent} from '../../../app/components/loading.component';

import { ProductModel} from '../../models/product.model'

@Component({
    selector: 'products',
    templateUrl: '../../app/components/product/product.html',
    providers: [ProductService, PaginationService, NotificationsService],
    directives: [PaginationControlsCmp, SimpleNotificationsComponent, LoadingComponent],
    pipes: [PaginatePipe]
})

export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
private data: Observable<any[]>;
private id: number;
private partners: Observable<any[]>;
isAuthorized: boolean = false;
private status: string;
public config: IPaginationInstance = {
    id: 'custom',
    itemsPerPage: 10,
    currentPage: 1
};
product: ProductModel;
public options = {
    timeOut: 3000,
    lastOnBottom: true,
    clickToClose: true,
    maxLength: 0,
    maxStack: 7,
    showProgressBar: true,
    preventDuplicates: false,
    rtl: true,
    animate: "scale",
    position: ["right", "top"]
};

constructor(
    private productService: ProductService,
    private notificationService: NotificationsService) {
    this.status = 'loading';
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getProducts()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.isAuthorized = true;
            this.data = data;
            this.product.Apim = data.Apim;

            this.status = 'active';
        },
        error => {
            console.log("error while retriving product");
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Ccreate a service and store the data in the service. If you need help understanding the services read more about them [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html)

Comment: I updated my component

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible way is to use a common service and use that service to retrieve and store/hold that data. You can see this in example of [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service).

Another way is to use cookies to store such data and in each component you read that data from cookie, but cookie has limitation in terms of how much data you can store there.

Third option is to harness the power of local storage.

Answer (score 0):

We have to use provider for data management.

```
export class TestProvider {

data: any;

constructor(private http: Http) {
  this.data = null;
}

getProductById(id) {
   if (this.data) {
      return Promise.resolve(this.data);
   }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('path/to/data.json')
      .map(res => res.json())
     .subscribe(data => {
       this.data = data;
       resolve(this.data);
      });
   });
  }
 }
```

So if 'data' object have values then method will return the data object and will not connect to api.

I Hope this will solve your issue.